# How to fetch certain columns in Laravel using eloquent on "User::with" query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I have eloquent query in Laravel with this statement. It's relationships are all setup correctly and my question is about limiting the data it's fetching to certain columns on the "with" data.

As you can see, "userIsFollowingAuthor" relationship table is one of 3 tables I am including as relations.

But, how do you select only specific columns from these individual relationships?  For example I only need the "first_name" and "avatar_id" from this relationship above mentioned, not the full data set.

```
$user_dashboard_data = User::with('profile', 'favorites', 'userIsFollowingAuthor')->find($user->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain the eager loading query by passing a closure as the value and the relation as the key in the with array input:

```
User::with(['userIsFollowingAuthor' => function($q) {
    $q->select(['column1', 'column2']);
});
```

However, you're using find (retrieving one model), so there's really no benefit to eager loading.

You can query any relation by using the relationship method:

```
$user->userIsFollowingAuthor()->select(['column1', 'column2'])->get();
```